# Issue with Z-Order

Tags: excel, z-order, vba

I have multiple shapes and checkboxes in a spreadsheet. I want to create a function that places a particular shape to front (a higher Z-order than its peers) when its corresponding checkbox is clicked. This is the code that I currently have:

```
Sub CheckBox3_Click()
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
Sheet1.Shapes("blueoval").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If
End Sub
```

I get Run-time Error '424' whenever I run this code. I am new to VBA for excel, so any help would be greatly appreciated. What's wrong with this code? What's missing? etc.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

Check that:

Your checkbox is an ActiveX control and not a Form control. 
The checkbox name is CheckBox3.
You have a shape on Sheet1 called blueoval.
The sheet name with the blue oval is actually Sheet1 (check this in the Visual Basic Editor).
In the Visual Basic Editor, select Tools > References and make sure there are no references marked MISSING.
Your code is on the worksheet where the checkbox is and not in a separate module.