# ZOrder In Code Is Not Working For Me

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the ZOrder of an object by Code in VBA Excel and I Get Error 438 Object doesn't Support this property or method
Here is my code

```
Sheets("print Preview").Shapes("barn").ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

this code Is being Run from a Macro.

The print preview tab is selected and the shape barn is selected but It will not move to back.
Is this code in error.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632547/vba-excel-issue-with-zorder-help-with-debugging-code

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ".ShapeRange" portion.
Use:

```
Sheets("print Preview").Shapes("barn").ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Cheers!